# File operations conflicts

Tags: delphi, pascal

I’m writing a program which is continously looking for new files in a directory. After it extracts data from each file and makes some treatments with it, the files are moved to another directory containing all scanned files.

Imagine I’m copying a new file in the scanned directory while my program is running. Can a file which has not finished copying be treated (and then produce unforeseen results), or is it locked by the System ?

Now, imagine two instances of the program are running on two different computers, continously scanning the same folder. What can happen if both instances are trying to move the same file ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is very imprecise. Define "copying". Are you reading or writing. Copying involves a read of the source and a write of the destination. What share mode are you using? Are you allowing multiple instances complete freedom to operate on the same files at the same time with no synchronisation? This question appears back to front. Instead of asking about your solution (which sounds dubious at best) you should ask how to solve the original problem.

Comment: There are ways to hook an event to directory changes, no need to poll for changes.

Comment: @LURD - In theory. IRL it is not that simple. The underlying system operates by polling and in some (not so) rare conditions misses a few changes.

Comment: @mg30rg, the changes are kept in a buffer and this buffer is protected for overrun, so yes there is a possibility to miss some changes when lots of files are updated. There is also another OS system, "change journals" which captures all changes. I have not seen any implementation of using them though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a project that does much the same thing. Another application is receiving data from a feed and writing files to a folder. My application is processing those files by opening them, acting on them in some way, writing them to another folder, then deleting them.

The strategy I used in the application that does the processing and deleting is to simply open them like this:

```
TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead OR fmShareDenyWrite);
```

If the file that is being opened is still being written by another process, the above will fail, and can likely be opened successfully on a subsequent iteration.